# How to add story points to card display in Greenhopper Kanban Work view?

Tags: agile

The configuration options in admin so far only allow me to edit the display of cards in Classic views.

Answer (score 1):

This explains how you can add story points with other templates.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/Story+Point

Comment: thanks. that gave some hints for enabling story points for issue types besides stories and epics, but did not help in getting them to appear in the Rapid Board layout.

Comment: Hi Shoba, while this link may be helpful, if the link were to ever break, your answer would be useless. Since the goal of PMSE is to be a resource of knowledge for years to come, consider making an [edit] to your post to quote some of the information from the link. This will make your answer more useful to future visitors. Good luck! :)